# if(str == NULL || str.length() == 0) get error

Tags: c++, atoi

Here is the code for a leetcode algorithm problem:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int myAtoi(string str) {
        if(str == NULL || str.length() == 0) return 0;
        int pos = true;
        int result = 0;
        int i = 0;
        if(str.charAt(0) == '+' || str.charAt(0) == '-') {
            ++i;
            if(str.charAt(0) == '-') pos = false;
        }
        for(; i != str.length(); ++i) {
            if(str.charAt(i) >= '0' && str.charAt(i) <= '9') {
                result = result*10 + (int)(str.charAt(i)-'0');
            }
        }
        if(!pos) result=-result;
        if(result > INT_MAX) return INT_MAX;
        if(result < INT_MIN) return INT_MIN;
        return result;
    }
};
```

And I got a Compile Error

```
Line 4: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ and ‘long int’)
```

So what's wrong with the code?

Comment: It looks like the problem is that it's actually Java code thinly disguised as C++.

Answer (score 8):

`str` is object of type [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), not a pointer, it cannot be `NULL`. Use just `str.empty()` instead of both checks.
There is also no function `charAt` in string.

Answer (score 5):

`NULL` is an integer constant, usually defined as `0` or `0L`. You cannot compare a string with an int. `str.length() == 0` and `str.empty()` are two good alternatives.